# how do i go about doing this file path?

Tags: java, android, path, hardcode

I made an app that i'm am working on updates for and in the old version I hard coded the file path like this

```
"/data/data/my.app.here/troll"
```

so now I am trying to do an update and I am trying to use something similar to

```
Context.getFilesDir()
```

but that returns

```
/data/user/0/my.app.here/files
```

the app info is stored on the troll file and when I push updates I don't want to use another path and have them start their information all over again. What's the best way to resolve this situation?

Comment: As I understand `/data/user/` is just a symlink of `/data/data`, so technically it should point to the same path. Do you manage to find your file in `/user/0/your.app/`?

Comment: I cant even find that directory and i tried changing it how i have above and its 2 different files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone kindly tell me the best way to resolve this situation?

Call `getParentFile()` on the `File` returned by `getFilesDir()` to get its parent directory. Your `troll` file should be in there. That wasn't a great place to put a file, and so YMMV.

If your concern is the `/data/user/0/`, that will be handled by Android and should map to `/data/data/` when the primary user is the one running your app.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks for the info, now I know for next time. Im just working on my own stuff im a senior in college I plan to really make a living from this. this isn't the first time you helped me thanks a lot.